# RuntimeError, working on IA tryna use a pre-trained BERT model

Tags: python, tensorflow, classification, pytorch, bert-language-model

Hi here is a part of my code to use a pre-trained bert model for classification:

```
    model = BertForSequenceClassification.from_pretrained(
     "bert-base-uncased", # Use the 12-layer BERT model, with an uncased vocab.
     num_labels = 2, # The number of output labels--2 for binary classification.
                    # You can increase this for multi-class tasks.   
     output_attentions = False, # Whether the model returns attentions weights.
     output_hidden_states = False, # Whether the model returns all hidden-states.
    )
```

...

```
for step, batch in enumerate(train_dataloader):

b_input_ids = batch[0].to(device)
    b_input_mask = batch[1].to(device)
    b_labels = batch[2].to(device)

outputs = model(b_input_ids, 
                token_type_ids=None,
                attention_mask=b_input_mask, 
                labels=b_labels)
```

but then I receive this error message:

> RuntimeError: Expected tensor for argument #1 'indices' to have scalar
>   type Long;

but got torch.IntTensor instead (while checking arguments for embedding)
So I think I should transform my `b_input_ids` to tensor but don't know how to do it.
Thanks a lot in advance for your help everyone !

Answer (score 0):

Finally succeed using .to(torch.int64)